# Manually set Google Maps directions language

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am currently using the [GMaps.JS](http://hpneo.github.com/gmaps/examples/routes_advanced.html), which displays directions based on the user's browser preference. Since I live in Latin America, where computers are usually setup in English, I was wondering if there is a way for me to forcibly make the Maps API use Spanish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering if there is a way for me to forcibly make the Maps API
>   use Spanish.

Yes.

If you wish to change the Maps API to ignore the browser's language setting and force it to display information in a particular language, you can add an optional language parameter to the  tag when including the Maps API javascript code, specifying the language to use.

For example, to display a Maps API application in Japanese, add &language=ja to the  tag as shown below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=ja">
```

Source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics